# Query on ThreadSafeClientConnManager (Apache HttpClient 4.1.1)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Am using ThreadSafeClientConnManager
Apache HttpComponenets-Client4.1.1 for my connection pool.

When am releasing the connection back to the pool i say:

> cm.releaseConnection(client,-1,TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
>   cm.closeExpiredConnections(); cm.closeIdleConnections(20,
>   TimeUnit.SECONDS);

[Here cm is object of ThreadSafeClientConnManager]
and as mentioned in the javadoc  releaseConnection(ManagedClientConnection conn,          long validDuration,TimeUnit timeUnit) am setting valid duration to -ve (<=0) value.

But when i see server logs i find that:

org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
2011-08-17 14:12:48.992 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager Released connection is not reusable.
2011-08-17 14:12:48.992 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute Releasing connection [HttpRoute[{}->http://server-name:port][null]
2011-08-17 14:12:48.992 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 [org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute] Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2011-08-17 14:12:48.993 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 [org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager] Closing expired connections
2011-08-17 14:12:48.993 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 [shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute] Closing expired connections
2011-08-17 14:12:48.993 DEBUG   Other        Thread-257 [shaded.org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager] Closing connections idle longer than 20 SECONDS

Here i see in the logs that "Released connection is not reusable"
Does that mean that "-1 " is not making the connection reusable  and connections are closed instead of returning to pool?
If so can any one please suggest how can i make it reusable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default HTTP connection released back to the manager are considered non-reusable. If a connection remains in a consistent state it should be marked as re-usable by using `ManagedClientConnection#markReusable()` prior to being released back to the manager.

Comment: Hi, ManagedClientConnection.setSocketTimeout(10000) will ensure that if the connection is not released within 10s then timeout will occur. After that will the connection be closed or relased back to the pool ?

Comment: No, it will not, if you are using ThreadSafeClientConnManager directly. It is your responsibility to inform the connection manager that the connection is no longer used (or usable).